# How to convert digits in a string into words using Python NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tokenize

I am trying to write a function that will:

- Take a string as an input
- Check if if there are any digits in it
- Convert digits into words

For example, "Hello 5, 123" would be converted to "Hello five, one hundred twenty  three".

The code I have is: 
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
    from num2words import num2words

```
def conv_mytext(text, **keyword_parameters):
    if('convert_digits' in keyword_parameters):
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(text)
    for w in word_tokens:
        if int(w):
            word_tokens[w] = num2words(w)
        else:
            continue
    return text
```

I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Hello'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How about this: https://pastebin.com/WwFCjYtt ?

Comment: use `try int(w) ... except ...` instead of `if int(w) ... else ...`

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is that `int()` is not a predicate function - you're expecting it to work as though it were something like `isInt()`, when it actually will attempt to convert the value you pass to an int.

"Hello", the first token in your sequence of course cannot be converted to an int, and because of this, calling `int("Hello")` produces a `ValueError`, indicating that "Hello" is probably not a base-10 number.

You should look at other ways of testing if a string is number-like. The most straightforward would be to execute that conversion in a try/catch block, allowing you to identify the ValueError and move on safely once it's noticed that the string isn't a number.

Another would be to use a regular expression to identify if the string is number like. The regular expression `^\d+$` would work for integers. If the string matches that expression, then the string consists solely of digits and can be passed to `num2words`.